# How to stop Android Studio emulator from freezing my desktop keyboard and mouse?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Within a few minutes of trying out the emulator it seems to freeze my desktop (running Ubuntu 20.04).  After this happened I noticed however that desktop apps such as browsers playing clips were still working.  Even my caps lock key made a sound (although it did not change the keyboard light indicator).

At first, I thought this was likely due to hardware and hax and the like.  I wasn't able to change this in the bios but eventually I learned to just try a couple of devices that allowed software emulator, such as  the Nexus 6.

However even with this, the 'freezes' continued.  As I noirmally use a KVM devioce to share keyboard and mouse and screen between my pcs, I then tried plugging in a different keyboard directly into the specific desktop I am using (i.e. not thru the KVM switch) and it worked!  For a while...  but then it also froze.  Then I continued on, using a small mobile keyboard device that includes a small track pad and so far this has kept working.

My suspicion so far is that, given I am using an Android Emulator, somehow the emulator is 'stealing focus' or grabbing control or something like like for my keyboard / mouse.

The same happened with my mouse, initially stopped working through the KVM switch setup that I have.  Then a direct USB plugin wireless mouse worked even though the KVM connected one had stopped working.  Then this second mouse stopped working and I was down the the small keyboard approach which has a little trackpad that kept working.

Question: How to stop the emulator taking my keyboard and mouse focus effectively freezing my existing external devices.

Note: The issue is about my **desktop** keyboard, NOT the emulator keyboard, i.e. when it freezes my whole desktop in not accessible through its keyboard and mouse.

Comment: I was facing the same issue, using API 28/29 emulator works without any issues, also consider switching to the proprietary graphics drivers. HTH.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to change your driver to the proprietary Nvidia driver. You could do it in

> Software and update → Additional driver

then reboot and the problem should be solved.

**Note:**
In some cases changing the nouveau driver to NVidia might freeze Ubuntu at boot (before login screen) for some users.